# warning popup at javascripts of webpages in webbrowser in c# application

Tags: c#

Using a webbrowser control in c# project shows me a warning whenever a page with javascript is navigated.Is there a method to suppress those messages ?

default web browser : google chrome

Here is the warning picture : http://www.kompyooter.com/?qa=39/warning-popup-at-javascript-of-pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.scripterrorssuppressed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

I believe that will do exactly what you want.  You just need to set the property to `true`.  By default it is `false`.